# Querying SQL using Php and outputting geojson for a GeoPolygon

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial, geojson

Output geojson for a Geo Polygon in PHP stored in MySQL database

I have tried many things including geoPHP plugin https://geophp.net/geos.html but no success so far, also tried using ST_AsGeoJSON but no use

```
$sql = "select ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeomFromText('coordinates')) from buildings where id = 1";
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html

I am trying to achieve a output similar to this

```
"shape":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[53.294974,-6.426631],[53.294847,-6.426419],[53.294289,-6.426888],[53.294326,-6.427194],[53.294974,-6.426631]]]}
```

This is my insert statement -

```
INSERT INTO `mrp_buildings` (
  `buildingId`, `companyId`, `name`, `noOfFloors`,
  `coordinates`, `city`, `country`, `address`, `phone`,
  `email`) VALUES (
    '1', '1', 'My Sample Building', '4',
    PolyFromText('POLYGON((33.294974 -2.426631, 53.294847 -6.426419,
      73.294289 -6.426888, 13.294326 -6.427194, 43.294974 -6.426631,
      33.294974 -2.426631))'), 'Dublin', 'Ireland', 'Mayor Street', '089449 8500', 'email@example.ie ');
```

Any suggestions -

Comment: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Take your DB row, craft an array with the JSON keys, then `json_encode()`.

Of course, the way you have stored the coordinates is messy, really you need to turn $coordinates into an array like so:

```
$coordinates = [
    [
        55.123456,
        0.123456,
    ],
    [
       //etc
    ]
```

In order to do that, you need to get rid of the stuff you don't need first:

```
$string = $row['coordinates']; /* POLYGON((33.294974 -2.426631, 53.294847 -6.426419,
      73.294289 -6.426888, 13.294326 -6.427194, 43.294974 -6.426631,
      33.294974 -2.426631)) */

$string = str_replace('POLYGON', '', $string); /* ((33.294974 -2.426631, 53.294847 -6.426419,
  73.294289 -6.426888, 13.294326 -6.427194, 43.294974 -6.426631,
  33.294974 -2.426631)) */

 $string = str_replace('(', '', $string);
 $string = str_replace(')', '', $string); // remove brackets

 $coords = explode(',' $string);
```

At that point you'll have an array of coordinates, but both X & Y are the one value separated by a space, so we need to explode that too.

```
$coordinates = [];
foreach ($coords as $co) {
    $ex = explode(' ', $co);
    $coordinates[] = [
        $ex[0], $ex[1];
    ];
}
```

Finally you can create the array to JSON encode:

```
$array = []; //empty array

$array['shape'] = [
    'type' => 'Polygon',
    'coordinates' => $coordinates
];

$json = json_encode($array);
```

I hope this helps! If you can, try storing the coordinates in the DB without the additional stuff to save you all this hassle!

Comment: thanks del but i think you didnt understood my question the data stored is GeoPolygon (its a type of Spatial data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database) and in javascript there is ways to get this type of data using coordinates.ST_ASGeoJson() but i am struggling with the php implementation of it

Comment: GeoPolygon is a DB type? Can you var dump the column for me then?

Comment: The coloumn is type - geometry